# Unable to set Background Color for NULL values in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, colors, null, expression, iif

I have a requirement to set Red colour for Outcome column = NULL values

Design below: 
[image: Design]

I am using below expression on the Count(StudentID) Text box:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Outcome.Value), "Red", "Transparent")
```

For Outcome textbox, I am using this expression:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Outcome.Value), "NULL", Fields!Outcome.Value)
```

But I am unable to see any color change.

Preview:
[image: Preview]

Can you please suggest how to resolve this?

Thanks,

AR

Comment: Try =IIF(Fields!Outcome.Value = "NULL", "Red", "Transparent") in the expression for the Fill Color.

Comment: Tried that but doesn't work :(

Comment: I tried =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Outcome.Value= "NULL", "Red", "Transparent") but it sets to Red background for all 0 values, whereas I just want NULL column to be highlighted.

Comment: Does it work if you use your `Outcome_specific` field that the column is tied to? If only the EMS row/NULL column cell is RED, then it sounds like `Outcome` does have data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Me.Value function to refer to the actual value of the cell you are setting the color expression for, rather than referring to the value of a Field.

=IIf(Me.Value = "NULL","Red","Transparent")

Answer (score 0):

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Apr.Value), "Aqua","Transparent")
```

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, please explain your answer..